# "The underlying connection was closed" with SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 Template Builder

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

When connecting to the CMS from Template Builder (TB) installed on a 64 bit Windows 7 laptop, we occasionally get the following error:

```
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.CompoundTemplates.DomainModel.Model.Login(Uri contentManager, NetworkCredential credentials)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.UI.CompoundTemplateDesigner.DesignerForm.LogonAs(Uri uri, Exception initialError)
```

This error only seems to occur when accessing from a client machine, and never seems occur when connecting from TB installed on the CMS server itself. This also does not seem to be CMS server specific, as the error also occurs intermittently when connecting to other environments and other client installs. I have tried re-installing TB, but the issue remains.

Has anyone else experienced similar issues, or have suggestions on what may be causing the error?

Comment: Does this happen when you Run a template? Or also when loading/saving a template? Once you have this on a machine, does it keep occurring? Or does the template run/load/save fine if you try again?

Comment: Any Proxy configured? I had similar connection issues because the Proxy used by the company I worked at.

Comment: It sometimes happens when I connect, and sometimes when I run. There are no proxies involved - Sometimes a VPN though - No real pattern on when it occurs :(

Comment: Reason I asked about Run vs Load/Save is that a TcmTemplateDebugHost.exe process is spawned for every Template Builder instance that runs templates. If that process dies, it will be respawned, but I have seen an occasional error message when the process is gone. A second Run (F5) would typically work fine though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can happen if there are too many connections open on the CM Server hosting the Templating Web Service.

Try restarting the server. If still continues add this following config in Templating web service:

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" maxRequestLength="102375" ></httpRuntime>
```

This will leave the file in `../Tridion/Templating/web.config` looking something like the following:

```
<configuration>
  <tridionConfigSections>
    <sections>
      <clear />
      <add filePath="..\config\Tridion.ContentManager.config" />
    </sections>
  </tridionConfigSections>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" maxRequestLength="1023750"/>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
    <identity impersonate="false" />
  </system.web>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="cmeWebRoot" value="WebUI" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks @Bappi, that helped - I think there may have also been some issues with the maxRequestLength, ans we have a very large number of publications. I have added my updated web.cofig to your answer